# How to determine the overall pixel values of an image to set the threshold value

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, binary, threshold

I'm a Matlab newbie. I tried to load an image and perform background subtraction on it. But, I don't know how to determine the threshold value based on my result. I have tried using histogram and graythres to determine the threshold value from my image. I need some suggestions on how to determine the threshold values.

Here is my code:

```
i2=imread('1cars.jpeg');
b1=rgb2gray(i2);
a1=medfilt2(b1);
result1= a1-a;
a2=imadjust(result1);

figure, imshow(a2);
level=graythresh(a2)
bw1=im2bw(a2,level);
bw=bwareaopen(bw1,50);
figure, imshow(bw);
image=getframe(gcf)
imwrite(image.cdata, strcat('result for 1 cars.jpg'));
```

Comment: I have found that for some images, a threshold of 28 works well. Joking aside, without the original image, and an indication of what it is that you want to segment, it's very difficult to help.

Comment: You mention you tried `graythresh` and `hist`. Why aren't you satisfied with the results of these methods?